# Why is the second derivative of Cumulant Generating Function positive?

Tags: probability-theory, cumulants

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Some_properties_of_the_cumulant_generating_function) states (without reference) that the cumulant generating function of a random variable has the property

> Its first derivative ranges monotonically in the open interval from the infimum to the supremum of the support of the probability distribution, and its second derivative is strictly positive everywhere it is defined, except for the degenerate distribution of a single point mass.

I think the strict positivitivity of second derivative boils down to the claim that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{x Z}\right) \mathbb{E}\left(Z^2 e^{x Z}\right)>\mathbb{E}\left(Z e^{x Z}\right)^2
$$
whenever the expectations exist, where $Z$ is any non-degenerate random variable. Is this correct?

Is there any good reference for the properties of Cumulant Generating Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the inequality is correct. A proof of the inequality is quite simple: Let $Q$ be the probability measure on the sample space of $Z$ defined by $\frac {dQ} {dP}=\frac {e^{zZ}} {Ee^{zZ}}$. Then the inequality  says $(E_QZ)^{2} \leq E_Q Z^{2}$ and strict inequality holds except when $Z$ is a  constant.

Comment: Is $P$ the probability measure of $Z$?

Comment: Yes, $P$ is the original probability measure on the space where $Z$ is defined.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit the meaning $\frac {dQ} {dP}=e^{zZ}$? I haven't seen definitions like this. Thanks.

Comment: $Q$ is defined by $Q(E)=\int_E e^{zZ} dP$. Are you familiar with Radon-Nikodym Theorem?

Comment: I can see that $(E_Q(Z))^2=\mathbb{E}\left(Z e^{x Z}\right)^2$. By why is $E_Q(Z^2) \le \mathbb{E}\left(e^{x Z}\right) \mathbb{E}\left(Z^2 e^{x Z}\right)$?

Comment: @ablmf I made a mistake. My $Q$ was not a proabability measure. You have to divide by $Ee^{zZ}$ to make it a probability measure. Now the requied inequality simply says that first moment (w.r.t  $Q$) is less than or equal to the square root of the second moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111174/discussion-between-ablmf-and-kavi-rama-murthy).